# Where to find a windows 7 AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-7

Where can I find a safe Windows 7 AMI (amazon virtual machine image) to use for my testing?  My first thought is to just use one for sale from a known source at Amazon.  Windows 7 AMIs seem hard to find simply by searching for "windows 7."  Still, I have to test some software.  Anyone know a good trick to finding one or perhaps an alternative?

thank you...

Comment: Just use Server 2008 R2 and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 is hard to find on EC2 as it is not supported.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=325787